# How to not capture whitespaces after a new line with regex in c++

Tags: c++, regex, newline, removing-whitespace

I am trying to catch comments from c/c++/java files but I cannot find a way to skip whitespaces that may exist after a new line.
My regex pattern is

`regex reg("(//.*|/\\*(.|\\n)*?\\*/)");`

For example in the following code (dont bother about the random code snippets, they could be anything...) I correctly catch comments:

```
// my  program in C++
#include <iostream>
/** playing around in
a new programming language **/
using namespace std;
```

and the output is:

```
// my  program in C++
/** playing around in
a new programming language **/
```

However, when i have code with whitespaces on a multiline comment like:

```
int main(){
        /* start always points to the first node of the linked list.
           temp is used to point to the last node of the linked list.*/
        node *start,*temp;
        start = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp = start;
        temp -> next = NULL;
        temp -> prev = NULL;
        /* Here in this code, we take the first node as a dummy node.
           The first node does not contain data, but it used because to avoid handling special cases
           in insert and delete functions.
         */
        printf("1. Insert\n");
```

I capture:

```
/* start always points to the first node of the linked list.
           temp is used to point to the last node of the linked list.*/
/* Here in this code, we take the first node as a dummy node.
           The first node does not contain data, but it used because to avoid handling special cases
           in insert and delete functions.
         */
```

instead of:

```
/* start always points to the first node of the linked list.
temp is used to point to the last node of the linked list.*/
/* Here in this code, we take the first node as a dummy node.
The first node does not contain data, but it used because to avoid handling special cases
in insert and delete functions.
*/
```

How can I get around it within the regex pattern to avoid this?

***NOTE***: If possible, I would like to avoid string manupulators etc, just with regex modification.

Comment: That is impossible. Remove the whitespace after getting the matches with another regex or plain code. And do not use `/\\*[\\d\\D]*?\\*/`, use a better regex, like `/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why are you using `malloc` and `printf` in a C++ program?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The code snippets are random dont bother about them, could be anything.

Comment: @GeoPapas, you could use a second regex on the already filtered data, which  reduces multiple whitespaces to one.

Comment: [OT]: Raw string may help to avoid extra `\ ` : `reg(R"((//.*|/\*[\d\D]*?\*/))");`

Comment: *NOTE: I do not want to do this with string manupulators etc, just with regex modification.* makes this question impossible to answer.

Comment: Are you ok to iterate over captured texts ? (as you may have non capturing group).

Comment: @Jarod42 I was thinking about doing it without any extra iterators or <algorithm> lib functions. As Wiktor said it seems impossible but I didnt know. I was hoping someone knew how to do it with a non-capturing group or something.

Comment: @Jarod42 Nice tip btw! Thanks!

Comment: I mean it, you cannot match discontinuous text. You need 2 steps: 1) match with what you have, and replace the spaces with `(^|\n)[^\S\r\n]+`/`$1`, or 2) pre-replace all the spaces with the regex above, and then match with your regex.

Comment: I mean that with something like `(/*)((..\n)(?:\s*))(*/)`, you may capture all sub-parts of your comment and skipping leading spaces. (but post processing your current result seems simpler btw).

Comment: Try to use an option that is an OR of . and newline instead of . — something like `.|\n` or `[.|\n]`.  In http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/ it says that . is **not newline**, it is easy for you to wrongly think that it could mean **any character**.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you can, it would be nice to answer the question with your first suggestion of `1) match with what you have, and replace the spaces with ...` so we can close it. Btw, that regex did not work for me. Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: Let me put my kids to bed, I will write an answer then. The regex is working, you must have copied/pasted/used it wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much! Regarding the regex I have copied it as it is but it does not capture anything. You have to consider that the text I am trying to capture is from the whole string, including `\n`s, as it is in the question's penultimate codebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment above.

It is impossible to match discontinuous text. Instead, you can match a part of a text with a regex and then post-process the matched (or captured) value with another regex or with string manipulations.

Here is an example (not the best, just to show the concept):

```
string data("int main(){// Singleline content\n        /* start always points to the first node of the linked list.\n           temp is used to point to the last node of the linked list.*/\n        node *start,*temp;\n        start = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));\n        temp = start;\n        temp -> next = NULL;\n        temp -> prev = NULL;\n        /* Here in this code, we take the first node as a dummy node.\n           The first node does not contain data, but it used because to avoid handling special cases\n           in insert and delete functions.\n         */\n        printf(\"1. Insert\n\");");
    //std::cout << "Data: " << data << std::endl;
    std::regex pattern(R"(//.*|/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)");
    std::smatch result;

    while (regex_search(data, result, pattern)) {
        std::cout << std::regex_replace(result[0].str(), std::regex(R"((^|\n)[^\S\r\n]+)"), "$1") << std::endl;
        data = result.suffix().str();
    }
```

See [the IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/ubW6ef)

**NOTE**: Raw string literals simplify regex definition.

The `R"(//.*|/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)"` matches either `//` + any 0+ characters but a newline (singleline comments) and `/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/` matches `/*` followed with 0+ non-`*`s followed with 1+ `*`s that is followed with 0+ sequences of a character other than `/` and `*` and then 0+ non-`*` and then 1+ `*`s  (multiline comments). This multiline comment is much more efficient than the one you have since it is written acc. to the unroll-the-loop technique.

I removed the first *horizontal* whitespace(s) on a *line* with `regex_replace(result[0].str(), std::regex(R"((^|\n)[^\S\r\n]+)"), "$1")`: `(^|\n)[^\S\r\n]+` matches and captures a start-of-string anchor or a newline followed with 1+ characters other than non-whitespace, CR, and LF.